# How to simply find coord's of Image B (smaller ) inside of image A (screenshot /big)?

Tags: c#, image, bitmap

I am trying to make a basic tool which will automatically move the mouse to a menu, and select from a drop-down menu the thing that's been selected.

So, this is the bit, that I'm trying to get my mouse to navigate to, specifically the "saimon" part. I will refer to this screenshot as A

[image: _]

The screenshot of the user's window, is a bigger picture than A. I just want to navigate to A's section within that screen.

Hopefully you understand the objective here.

Anyways, I was trying to do something simple like using an If statement, to see if I would find that icon within the screenshot, and if I did. It would navigate to those coordinates (I could input it manually, by having the user put the menu in a specific location OR grab the coordinates automatically). If it did not match, I would just say an error.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/130870/discussion-on-question-by-harmz7-how-to-simply-find-coords-of-image-b-smaller).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This answer uses OCR to find the location X,Y coordinates of the text 'Saimon'

You download [TessNet(2)](http://www.pixel-technology.com/freeware/tessnet2/)

Tessnet2 is a .NET 2.0 Open Source OCR assembly using Tesseract engine.

You can implement code similar to this:

```
using System;

namespace OCRTest
{
    using System.Drawing;

    using tessnet2;

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            try
            {
                var image = new Bitmap(@"C:\OCRTest\saimon.jpg");
                var ocr = new Tesseract();
                ocr.SetVariable("tessedit_char_whitelist", "0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz.,$-/#&=()\"':?"); // If digit only
                //@"C:\OCRTest\tessdata" contains the language package, without this the method crash and app breaks
                ocr.Init(@"C:\OCRTest\tessdata", "eng", true); 
                var result = ocr.DoOCR(image, Rectangle.Empty);
                foreach (Word word in result){
                    if(word.contains("aimon")){
                        Console.WriteLine("" + word.Confidence + " " + word.Text + " " +word.Top+" "+word.Bottom+ " " +word.Left + " " +word.Right);
                    }
                }

                Console.ReadLine();
            }
            catch (Exception exception)
            {

            }
        }
    }
}
```

You should be able to use these coordinates to automate your mouse to click.

To [test online with another OCR](http://www.free-ocr.com/) how OCR works, please provide your screenprint and check their results. OCR is so good these days!

Comment: @SimpleVar: Please correct my post if I made typo's or write/add the code to use the coordinates to perform the actual mouseclick.

Comment: Why 'aimon' ? -> the first character is not always recognized correctly.

Comment: I see these azure-cloud advertisements on stackoverflow, about getting free hosting. Could anyone host this OCR solution in Azure, to show it in action?

Comment: This is a lot simpler to understand. Thanks friend. Have you got a skype or any other form of communication? If I have some questions, I'd love to be able to ask you for assistance or clarification.

Comment: @Tony_KiloPapaMikeGolf What should I write for exception?

Comment: Anything you want! [Educate yourself about exception handling](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/seyhszts(v=vs.110).aspx).